# Edit App.config C# Window form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Window Form App with C# and I want User is able to add more user in the app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <User>
    <add User1 ="Hoang Nam"></add>
    <add User2 ="Van Hien"></add>
  </User>
</configuration>
```

but I can not get the `<User>` from my app by `ConfigurationManager`
Did I did correct? Please help.
Thank you very much

Comment: You should add your code that uses the `ConfigurationManager` too.

Comment: Hello, Could you please explain more clear, I just starting with C# and Winform. Thank you

Comment: Why are you adding users to your config file?  The usual place for this information is a database.

Comment: Because I want to display these User in a combobox, then End User is able to add more user. I do not need to create that function in my Form. and these users are just the one who will perform a test that I want to record on DataBase. Thank you

Comment: You can do all that in a database.  What's to stop somebody opening up your config file and either deleting a user or adding one?

Comment: @DarrenYoung, It free to do that if user has demand.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class `Configuration` which is an inheritance of `ConfigurationElement` and then set your config like this:

```
public class Configuration : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("User", IsRequired = false)]
    public string User
    {
        get { return (string)this["User"]; }
        set { this["User"] = value; }
    }
}
```

You will be able to manage your configuration with an instance of this class

[Here the documentation from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement(v=vs.110).aspx)